# Update Where field is the lowest number

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I think I am coming at this from the wrong angle, but I just can't think of a way to make this work. My query is below:

```
UPDATE my_table AS T0 
JOIN my_table_2 AS T1
ON T0.timestamp = T1.timestamp  AND T0.id = T1.id

SET lat = lat + 1

WHERE T0.duration = 'd'
AND T0.unique >= 0 
AND T0.unique <= 5
```

I need to update where `T0.unique` equals the lowest number between 0 and 5. So basically if the above returns 3 rows because `T0.unique = 2` in one row, and `T0.unique = 3` in another row, and `T0.unique = 4` in another row, then I only want it to actually update where it's the lowest number, i.e. `T0.unique = 2`

I am hoping there is some MySQL syntax I am not aware of that will do this.

Comment: Note that unique is a reserved word in MySQL, making it a dubious choice for a column identifier.

Comment: JOIN on a subqeruy with SELECT MIN(unique) GROUP BY wahtever

Comment: What's the purpose of the join? Does it filter out a bunch of the values?

Comment: @TZHX Yeah the join is filtering out a lot of data, I probably should have left that out as it is not really relevent to the question.

Comment: @superphonic I assumed that would be the case, just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something. :)

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, all sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do something like:

```
UPDATE mytable AS T0
SET lat = lat + 1
WHERE T0.duration = 'd' AND T0.unique BETWEEN 0 AND 5
--- possible alternative to join, allows use of ORDER BY and LIMIT in statement
AND EXISTS ( SELECT T1.id FROM mytable2 AS T1 
    WHERE T0.timestamp = T1.timestamp AND T0.id = T1.id )
ORDER BY T0.unique ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This will update at most 1 record, and the `ORDER BY` makes sure it's the one with the lowest value in `unique` column.

Comment: @superphonic Oh, bollocks. Sorry. It looks like you can't use ORDER and LIMIT when it's a multi-table statement. Didn't know that.

Comment: @superphonic could you avoid the join with an `exists` in your where statements, or would that be an unacceptable performance drop?

Comment: Good idea... It's a one off query to re-jig some existing data, so performance isn't really a worry. I'll try a WHERE EXISTS

Comment: Sweet!! I removed the LIMIT as I didn't need it in this case, it worked a treat.

Comment: @superphonic Great! Glad I could help some. Sorry my answer wasn't useful at first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
UPDATE my_table t0 
  JOIN my_table_2 t1 
    ON t0.timestamp = t1.timestamp
   AND t0.id = t1.id
   SET t0.lat = t0.lat + 1 
 WHERE t0.duration = 'd'
   AND t0.unique BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and edit @Strawberry), but this is the same as my original query using different syntax.